# Basic question about $p$-adic expansions

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, absolute-value

I was recently introduced to the $p$-adic numbers, and have been asked to show that for $n > 0$, the $p$-adic expansion of $\frac{1}{1 - p^n}$ is $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p^{in}$.

Could someone tell me whether my solution is correct? It seems right to me, but I don't have much intuition for how these objects work yet:

Observe that for all $N$ we have $\sum_{i=0}^N p^{in} = \frac{1-(p^n)^{N+1}}{1-p^n}$. Taking the limit in the $p$-adic topology as $N \to \infty$, we obtain $\sum_{i=0}^\infty p^{in} = \frac{1}{1-p^n}$ as desired.

Comment: It looks just fine to me.

Comment: Looks good. How about applying what you know from high-school math about the sum of a geometric series?

Comment: @Lubin: Isn't that what I did? Haha.

Comment: The next (or already?) nice surprise is to learn that in $\;p-$adic analysis, a series converges iff the general term's sequence converges to zero..:>)